# Result of algorithm in reverse, Producer-Consumer solution using Semaphores

Tags: c, algorithm, semaphore

The Producer-Consumer problem is solved using this Semaphore algorithm where the Semaphore is decremented by the buffer size then the Semaphore is decremented by 1 signifying the critical section.

If these operations are happening consecutively back-to-back why is it not correct to decrement by 1 (the mutex) and then decrement the buffer size?

I know both the producer and consumer will go to sleep at the same time creating a deadlock but why does this minor switch cause the entire algorithm to fail?

```
BufferSize = 3;

semaphore mutex = 1;              // Controls access to critical section
semaphore empty = BufferSize;     // counts number of empty buffer slots
semaphore full = 0;               // counts number of full buffer slots

Producer()
{
  int widget;

  while (TRUE) {                  // loop forever
    make_new(widget);             // create a new widget to put in the buffer
    down(&empty);                 // decrement the empty semaphore
    down(&mutex);                 // enter critical section
    put_item(widget);             // put widget in buffer
    up(&mutex);                   // leave critical section
    up(&full);                    // increment the full semaphore
  }
}

Consumer()
{
  int widget;

  while (TRUE) {                  // loop forever
    down(&full);                  // decrement the full semaphore
    down(&mutex);                 // enter critical section
    remove_item(widget);          // take a widget from the buffer
    up(&mutex);                   // leave critical section
    up(&empty);                   // increment the empty semaphore
    consume_item(widget);         // consume the item
  }
}
```

**Code Source:** [Resource](http://cs.gmu.edu/cne/modules/ipc/purple/prodsem.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not correct because what if the producer enters the code section by wait(mutex) but then it finds out there are no empty blocks left so it has to wait on the empty semaphore. At the same time when a consumer tries to enter it has to wait on mutex as producer has locked mutex. Thus there is a deadlock as producer is waiting for consumer to consume and consumer is waiting for producer to signal(mutex)
This is not the case with original arrangement of mutex and semaphores where a producer or consumer is only allowed to wait on mutex when it has decremented the semaphore value. Hence no deadlock.